# HDFS file system, get latest folders using scala API

Tags: scala, hadoop, hdfs

Our application reads data from several HDFS data folders, folders get updated weekly/daily/monthly so based on the updated period we need to find the latest path and then read the data.

We would like to do this using programmatic way using scala, so is there libraries available?

We could only see but just wondering any better libraries available?
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/package-summary.html

Comment: You can also use Scala's built-in `process` libraries. If reading and manipulating the data use a framework that can read and process the data in parallel (such Spark or MapReduce).

Answer (score 1):

The linked library is the recommended way to use HDFS API programmatically without going through `hadoop fs` CLI scripts. Any other library you may find would be built using the same package.